# How to copy a value from one column to another based on a third column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a sample dataframe below:

```
   A  B     C D
0  1  2   Red  
1  4  5  Blue  
2  7  8   Red
```

Output

```
   A  B     C  D
0  1  2   Red  1
1  4  5  Blue  5
2  7  8   Red  7
```

I am trying to fill column D using a value from either column A or B depending on what is in C?

So for example, if for the first row, since C = Red, I want to fill D with what is in A. If C = Blue, I want to fill in D with what is in B.

```
df.loc[df['C'] == 'Red', 'D'] =   df['A']
df.loc[df['C'] == 'Blue', 'D'] =  df['B']
```

I think I've got the left assignments down, but struggling what to do on the right to reference the same row. Trying to avoid looping through manually and doing this somewhat efficiently.

Comment: Hi perhaps map the values

Comment: `df['D'] = np.select([df['C'] == 'Red', df['C'] == 'Blue'], [df['A'], df['B']], np.nan)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Thank you, this was the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
df['D'] = np.where(df.C == 'red', df.A, df.B)
```

Output

```
   A  B     C  D
0  1  2   red  1
1  4  5  blue  5
2  7  6   red  7
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up will loop automatically.  df.loc[df['C'] == 'Red', 'D'] =   df['A'] will loop through every row.  You have written this efficiently.